# Where to put clientId and signature in your Google Map API V3 request?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have written a JavaScript code. I wanted to use `durationInTraffic` in a request with Google Maps API V3. This feature is only available for Google Maps for Work customers.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#api_key) it says Maps for work customers should include their clientId and signature in their request. But where exactly do I put the clientId and signature in my request? Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?"></script>

</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; color: red;"> 
<form>
<input type="text" name="start" id="start" placeholder="Start"> --> <input type="text" name="ziel" id="ziel" placeholder="Ziel"><br>
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="stunde" id="stunde" placeholder="Stunde">:
<input type="text" name="minute" id="minute" placeholder="Minute">
<br>
<input type="text" name="tag" id="tag" placeholder="Tag">-
<input type="text" name="monat" id="monat" placeholder="Monat">-
<input type="text" name="jahr" id="jahr" placeholder="Jahr">

</form> 
<input type="submit" value="Los!" onClick="getRoute()">

    <div id="durationWithTraffic">Dauer mit Vekehr: </div>    
   <div id="durationWithoutTraffic">Dauer ohne Vekehr: </div>    
   <br>
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
function getRoute(){
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

   var myOptions = {
     zoom:7,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

    var startValue=document.getElementById('start').value;
    var zielValue=document.getElementById('ziel').value;

        var stundeValue=document.getElementById('stunde').value;
    var minuteValue=document.getElementById('minute').value;

    var tagValue=document.getElementById('tag').value;
    var monatValue=document.getElementById('monat').value;
    var jahrValue=document.getElementById('jahr').value;

//departure time in Epoch time
    var abfahrtsZeitValue=monatValue+"/"+tagValue+"/"+jahrValue+" "+stundeValue+":"+minuteValue;

        var request_withTraffic = {
            origin: startValue, 
            destination: zielValue,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            transitOptions: {
                     departureTime: new Date(abfahrtsZeitValue)
                     },
             durationInTraffic: true
        };

        var request_withoutTraffic = {
            origin: startValue, 
            destination: zielValue,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            transitOptions: {
                     departureTime: new Date(abfahrtsZeitValue)
                     },
             durationInTraffic: false
        };

   directionsService.route(request_withTraffic, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

         // Display the duration:
            document.getElementById('durationWithTraffic').innerHTML="Dauer mit Vekehr: "; 
            document.getElementById('durationWithTraffic').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";            
      }
   });

   directionsService.route(request_withoutTraffic, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
        {   
            document.getElementById('durationWithoutTraffic').innerHTML="Dauer ohne Verkehr: "; 
            document.getElementById('durationWithoutTraffic').innerHTML += 
            response.routes[0].legs[0].duration.value + " seconds";            
        }
   });
}
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide your client id and signature while calling your script,

Here is your map script

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&v=3.17&signature=base64signature"></script>
```

for reference

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/#client_id
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth#signature_examples

Comment: What is the "privateKey"? Is the "privateKey" the same as my "Crypto Key". If not, where do I find the "privateKey"?

Comment: The signature is required for many API calls, but for the example given above (which is a javascript google map load), Google now throws a "SignatureNotRequired" exception as you only need your client ID and they recommend against including a signature for security reasons.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages